# GNU parallel: How can I set the working directory when using "--nonall"?

Tags: gnu-parallel

When *not* using `--nonall`, the `--workdir ...` option ("create working dirs under ~/.parallel/tmp/ on the remote computers") works as expected:

```
$ parallel -S target-server --workdir ... pwd ::: ""
/home/myuser/.parallel/tmp/my-machine-7285-1
```

However, when I add the `--nonall` option, it no longer has any effect:

```
$ parallel --nonall -S target-server --workdir ... pwd ::: ""
/home/myuser
```

Even when specifying an *explicit* working directory such as `/home`, this works:

```
$ parallel -S target-server --workdir /home pwd ::: ""
/home
```

...but this doesn't:

```
$ parallel --nonall -S target-server --workdir /home pwd ::: ""
/home/myuser
```

Any ideas why `parallel` is ignoring `--workdir` when using `--nonall`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly a bug. Now registered in the bug list: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?46819

Feel free to add yourself as Cc if you want to be kept informed.